# Typescript + React useReducer hook error: Data object not assignable to parameter of type 'never'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am facing an error at this line

```
const [current, dispatch] = React.useReducer(Reducer, initialState)
```

I'm not certain what is the exact error, but based on the message, i interpret it to mean that 'initialState' variable is not strongly typed enough?

```
No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 5, '(reducer: ReducerWithoutAction<any>, initializerArg: any, initializer?: undefined): [any, DispatchWithoutAction]', gave the following error.

Argument of type '(state: State, action: Actions) => State | { data: DataType; searchParams: SearchType; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReducerWithoutAction<any>'.   Overload 2 of 5, '(reducer: (state: State, action: { type: Types; data: DataType; searchParams: SearchType; }) => State | { data: DataType; searchParams: SearchType; }[], initialState: never, initializer?: undefined): [...]', gave the following error.

Argument of type '{ data: { bleData: IbleData[]; bleSessions: IbleSessions[]; bleSummary: IbleSummary[]; message: string; }; searchParams: { PHONE_NUMBER: string; FROM: Date; TO: Date; errorMessage: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

(alias) const Reducer: (state: State, action: Actions) => State | {
    data: DataType;
    searchParams: SearchType; }[] import Reducer
```

**This is the EventContext.jsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Reducer, Actions, State, IbData, IbSessions, IbSummary } from "../reducers/EventsReducer"

const initialState: {
    data: {
      bData: IbData[];
      bSessions: IbSessions[];
      bSummary: IbSummary[];
      message: string;
    };
    searchParams: {
      PHONE_NUMBER: string;
      FROM: Date;
      TO: Date;
      errorMessage: string;
    };
  } = {
    data: {
      bData: [],
      bSessions: [],
      bSummary: [],
      message: ""
    },
    searchParams : {
      PHONE_NUMBER: "",
      FROM: new Date(),
      TO: new Date(Date.now() - 604800000),
      errorMessage: ""
    }
  }

const EventContext = React.createContext<{
  current: State;
  dispatch: React.Dispatch<Actions>;
}>({
  current: initialState,
  dispatch: () => null
});


const EventProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [current, dispatch] = React.useReducer(Reducer, initialState)

  return (
    <EventContext.Provider value={{ current, dispatch }}>
      {children}
    </EventContext.Provider>
  )
}

export { EventProvider, EventContext };
```

**This is EventsReducer.tsx**

```
enum Types {
  SET_DATA = 'SET_DATA'
}

export interface IbData {
  id: string;
  datetime: Date,
  ... 
}

export interface IbSessions {
  id: string,
  day_month: string,
  ...
}

export interface IbSummary {
  total_duration: number,
  phone_number: string,
  other_phone_number: string
}

export type DataType = {
  bData: IbData[];
  bSessions: IbSessions[];
  bSummary: IbSummary[];
  message: string;
}

type SearchType = {
  PHONE_NUMBER: string;
  FROM: Date;
  TO: Date;
  errorMessage: string;
}

export type State = {
  data: DataType;
  searchParams: SearchType;
};

export type Actions = 
  | { type: Types.SET_DATA; 
    data: DataType;
    searchParams: SearchType;
  }

export const Reducer = (
  state: State,
  action: Actions
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case Types.SET_DATA:
      return [
        {
          data: action.data,
          searchParams: action.searchParams
        }
      ];
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have some `[` `]` that are too much here

```
    case Types.SET_DATA:
      return [
        {
          data: action.data,
          searchParams: action.searchParams
        }
      ];
```

Or is this intended ?